# transform rotate doesn't work properly in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you transform rotate, it seems to work, but you have to move the mouse cursor to the top left of the browser for rotate to work. I want it to work when I move the mouse cursor relative to the center of the blue square element. What should I do?

```js
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const card = document.querySelector(".card");
  const body = document.querySelector("body");

  const w = card.clientWidth;
  const h = card.clientHeight;
  
  const bodyRect = body.getBoundingClientRect();
  const cardRect = card.getBoundingClientRect();
  const left = cardRect.left - bodyRect.left + (card.clientWidth/2);
  const top = cardRect.top - bodyRect.top + (card.clientHeight/2);
  
  console.log(`cardRect.left : ${cardRect.left}, bodyRect.left : ${bodyRect.left}, card.clientWidth/2 : ${card.clientWidth/2}`);
  console.log(`cardRect.top : ${cardRect.top}, bodyRect.top : ${bodyRect.top}, card.clientHeight/2 : ${card.clientHeight/2}`);
  
  const rotx = (e.pageY - top) / e.pageY;
  const roty = (e.pageX - left) / e.pageX;
  
  console.log(`roty : ${roty}, rotx : ${rotx}`)
  
  card.style.msTransform = `rotateX(${rotx}deg) rotateY(${roty}deg)`;
  card.style.webkitTransform = `rotateX(${rotx}deg) rotateY(${roty}deg)`;
  card.style.transform = `rotateX(${rotx}deg) rotateY(${roty}deg)`;
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #00f;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: perspective(400px);
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math is all over the place. Look at the rotation angles you compute/log, they are <5deg for almost the entire screen.

```js
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const card = document.querySelector(".card");
  
  const cardRect = card.getBoundingClientRect();
  const center = new DOMPoint(
    cardRect.x + cardRect.width/2,
    cardRect.y + cardRect.height/2
  );
  
  //turn 180deg/400px distance from the center
  const scale = 180/400;
  
  const rotY = (e.pageX - center.x) * scale; 
  const rotX = -(e.pageY - center.y) * scale;
  
  card.style.transform = `rotateX(${rotX}deg) rotateY(${rotY}deg)`;
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #00f;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: perspective(400px);
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your formulae for rotx and roty are wrong. Try these:

```
const rotx = e.pageY - card.clientHeight / 2;
const roty = e.pageX - card.clientWidth / 2;
```

Here is a snippet to demonstrate.

```js
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const card = document.querySelector(".card");
  const body = document.querySelector("body");

  const w = card.clientWidth;
  const h = card.clientHeight;
  
  const bodyRect = body.getBoundingClientRect();
  const cardRect = card.getBoundingClientRect();
  const left = cardRect.left - bodyRect.left + (card.clientWidth/2);
  const top = cardRect.top - bodyRect.top + (card.clientHeight/2);
  
  console.log(`cardRect.left : ${cardRect.left}, bodyRect.left : ${bodyRect.left}, card.clientWidth/2 : ${card.clientWidth/2}`);
  console.log(`cardRect.top : ${cardRect.top}, bodyRect.top : ${bodyRect.top}, card.clientHeight/2 : ${card.clientHeight/2}`);

  const rotx = e.pageY - card.clientHeight / 2;
  const roty = e.pageX - card.clientWidth / 2;
  
  console.log(`roty : ${roty}, rotx : ${rotx}`)
  
  card.style.msTransform = `rotateX(${rotx}deg) rotateY(${roty}deg)`;
  card.style.webkitTransform = `rotateX(${rotx}deg) rotateY(${roty}deg)`;
  card.style.transform = `rotateX(${rotx}deg) rotateY(${roty}deg)`;
});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #00f;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: perspective(400px);
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```